# Migrate database connection from WAS to TOMCAT 7

Tags: tomcat, datasource

I have a database connection in my WAS server.xml like that:

```
<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="ORACLEDriver" jndiName="jdbc/jndiNameExample">
    <properties.oracle
        URL="*******"
        password="****" user="****" />
</dataSource>

<jdbcDriver id="ORACLEDriver" libraryRef="ORACLE" />

<library id="ORACLE">
    <fileset dir="C:\route1\route" includes="ojdbc6.jar" />
</library>
```

How can I migrate this database connection to a TOMCAT 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ojdbc6.jar to tomcat lib directory.

tomcat server.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
        global="jdbc/jndiNameExample" 
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="20" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        minIdle="5" 
        name="jdbc/jndiNameExample" 
        password="password" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:ServiceName" 
        username="username"/>
```

tomcat context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/jndiNameExample"
          global="jdbc/jndiNameExample"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
<description>Oracle Datasource</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/jndiNameExample</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

Connection code

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env"); 
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("java:/comp/env/jdbc/jndiNameExample");
```

Comment: Thanks! I configured it like that, but it always throws this exception: NameNotFoundException the jndi name is no associated to this context.

Comment: Did you insert connection configuration into `<GlobalNamingResources></GlobalNamingResources>` in server.xml ?

Comment: Yes, is in GlobalNamingResources. I need to insert something in web.xml?

Comment: Yes, also need to insert following configuration into  WEB-INF/web.xml
 
`<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/jndiNameExample</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>`

Comment: i'm getting the same exception (javax.naming.NameNotFoundException, not found jndi in this context)

Comment: Get a context for the JNDI look up
    `Context ctx = new InitialContext();`
    `Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");`
      
    Look up a data source
   `javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("jdbc/jndiNameExample");`

Comment: `DataSource ds =(DataSource)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/jndiNameExample");`